# Multiple form submittion options in one form

Tags: php, html

So I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action='../performSQL.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='hidden_id' value='$id'>
<input type='date' name='porteringsdato' value='$dato' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<input type='text' id='fname' name='fname' value='$gsm' disabled style='text-align: center;' >
<input type='submit' class='button' style='background-color: red;' name='slettoppfølging' value='Slett oppfølging' onclick='clicked(event)' />
</form>
```

In `performSQL.php` I have these queries:

```
if (isset($_POST['slettoppfølging'])) {
    
    $id = $_POST['hidden_id'];
    
    $sql = "DELETE from followups WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    if ($stmt->error) {
        echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else {
        header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        // echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";
    }
    
    $stmt->close();
    $link->close();
    
}

if (isset($_POST['porteringsdato'])) {
    
    $id = $_POST['hidden_id'];
    $dato = $_POST['porteringsdato'];
    
    
    $sql = "UPDATE followups SET dato=? WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $dato, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    if ($stmt->error) {
        echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); // echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";
    
    $stmt->close();
    $link->close();
}
```

When changing the value of `porteringsdato`, the form gets submitted as it should, but when clicking the `slettoppfølging`, it looks like both of the above queries is running. First the slettoppfølging, and then porteringsdato, because the record gets deleted as it should, but I also get this error message each time in error_log:

```
[30-Mar-2021 09:49:02 Europe/Oslo] PHP Warning:  mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/xx/xxxxxx/performSQL.php on line 468
[30-Mar-2021 09:49:02 Europe/Oslo] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in /home/xx/xxxxxx/performSQL.php:469
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/xx/xxxxxx/performSQL.php on line 469
```

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Why would you expect anything else? Both fields are in the form, so they both are set when you submit.

Comment: `porteringsdato` will always be sent when you submit the form. `slettoppfølging` will be sent when you submit the form using the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `elseif` so you only check `$_POST['porteringsdato']` when the submit button isn't sent.

```
elseif (isset($_POST['porteringsdato'])) {
```

You could also just use `else`, since the `porteringsdato` input is always included whenever the form is submitted.